# Allocating Subarrays in Mergesort

Tags: recursion, memory, mergesort, allocation, divide-and-conquer

What's happening, folks.

So, I've done a fair amount of research on merge sort, and in spite of getting the "gist" of it, I am still baffled by how one is supposed to store the subarrays in order to merge them back together—in other words, save them somewhere so that they would "know" each other, as you would otherwise—in classic recursive fashion—have all these independent function calls returning data that I would assume would go out of scope.

Here's what I first thought: create a new array named "`subs`" to store the subarrays in upon each division (I also considered using a closure to do this and would like to know whether this is advisable). But, as you proceed to the next division, what are you gonna do—replace each element in `subs` with its subarrays? Then, you would be facing more costly work, especially once you consider how you're gonna move things around in `subs` in order to ensure that each subarray has its own index.

Heh—I have a bad feeling that this might be a far cry from what's actually supposed to be done. I understand that this algorithm is a classic example of the divide-and-conquer approach, but it's just strange to me that one couldn't just cut to the chase by splitting the array into all of its elements right off the bat (after all, that's the base case, and what would be wrong with throwing in a greedy approach to solving the problem?).

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Alright, so I figured it out.

To sum it up: I used indices to track where to place elements (and obviate the need for built-in list functions that may slow down runtime).

By using nested functions and a (hidden) pointer to the new array, I kept data in scope. An auxiliary array buffers data from the subarrays.

In retrospect, what I originally had in mind <s>vaguely resembled insertion sort</s> was, in fact, *bottom-up merge sort*. Having previously questioned the efficiency and purpose of top-down merge sort, I now understand that by breaking down the problem, it expedites comparisons and swaps (especially when operating on larger lists, <s>which insertion sort would prove to be less efficient in sorting</s>). I did not attempt to implement my initial idea because I did not have a clear enough picture of recursion and how data is passed.

```
#!/bin/python
import sys


def merge_sort(arr):

    def merge(*indices):           # indices = first, last, and pivot indices, respectively
        head, tail = indices[0], indices[1]
        pivot = indices[2]

        i = head
        j = pivot+1
        k = 0

        while (i <= pivot and j <= tail):
            if new[i] <= new[j]:
                aux[k] = new[i]
                i += 1
                k += 1
            else:
                aux[k] = new[j]
                j += 1
                k += 1
        while (i <= pivot):
            aux[k] = new[i]
            i += 1
            k += 1
        while (j <= tail):
            aux[k] = new[j]
            j += 1
            k += 1

        for x in xrange(head, tail+1):
            new[x] = aux[x-head]
        # end merge

    def split(a, *indices):      # indices = first and last indices, respectively
        head, tail = indices[0], indices[1]
        pivot = (head+tail) / 2

        if head < tail:
            l_sub = a[head:pivot+1]
            r_sub = a[pivot+1:tail+1]

            split(l_sub, head, pivot)
            split(r_sub, pivot+1, tail)
            merge(head, tail, pivot)
        # end split

    new = arr
    aux = list(new)
    tail = len(new)-1

    split(new, 0, tail)
    return new
    # end merge_sort


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loops = int(raw_input().strip())
    for _ in xrange(loops):
        arr = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(' '))
        result = merge_sort(arr)
        print result
```

Comment: Try code it your way and the classic way and see if that brings you any insights

Comment: OK. So far, I've been trying to code it the "classic" way, although I haven't reached the step where I could experiment with actually storing the subarrays. So far, I have just written the code for bisecting arrays and have the basic control flow for recursion down. I like your suggestion, as I am a firm believer in taking the dirty, hands-on route to learning anything. Wish me luck. Thank you!

Comment: if you get stuck, just add your code to your question. Don't add it as a comment, edit the question to add it.

Comment: Will do. Thanks, Dan

Comment: "just cut to the chase by splitting the array into all of its elements right off the bat ". This is exactly what a [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) does. It skips all of the recursion used to split up an array and begins by considering an array of *n* elements as *n* runs of size 1. Most libraries use some variation of bottom up merge sort.

Comment: For both top down and bottom up merge sort, it's faster to do a one time allocation of a temp array, then use indexing to "select" sub-arrays. The copy back in the merge function can be avoided by changing the direction of merge based on level of recursion for top down or based on pass for bottom up.

Comment: Well, I'll be damned―what I imagined was, in fact, bottom-up merge sort! Could you elaborate on the last part (with regards to changing direction)? Does what I did count as a onetime allocation of a temp array?